# How to retrieve a specific value from an array with keys and values in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to access a specific value in the array that is formed after my query.

```
$query = $views->find('all');
$results = $query->all();
$data = $results->toArray();
$results = $query->toArray();

echo $results[0];
```

the echo shows `{'id':1, 'date':2016-07-27,'amount':30}`

I just want to get the 30 from amount. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the property of the array

```
echo $results[0]['amount']
```

[php docs on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

get a single item:

```
$query = $views->findById($id);
//or
$query = $views->get($id);

echo $query->amount;
```

or if you want to get em all

```
$query = $views->find('all');

foreach ($query as $view) {
    echo $view->amount;
}
```